# NSURLSession with WatchOS 2.2 very slow

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsurlsession, apple-watch

I try to download some JSON data from a web server with NSURLSession in a WatchOS 2.2 app. The same code that runs flawlessly on the iPhone itself, takes forever on the watch (using the simulator).

I checked out this example: https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler, which has a function to download and display an image via NSURLSession, and it has the same problem.

The code of this example is:

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3186881240/fa714ece16d0fabccf903cec863b1949_400x400.png")!
    let conf = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: conf)
    task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, res, error) -> Void in
        if let e = error {
            print("dataTaskWithURL fail: \(e.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let d = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: d)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if self.isActive {
                    self.image.setImage(image)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    task!.resume()
```

Playing around with it, I figured out that if I change the code to

```
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

it works fine.

However, I cannot use this in my app because I need to setup delegates.

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: did u get any solution for it? data loading using NSURLSession takes too much time in watch OS 2.2 +

Comment: On watchOs 5, on a watch with cell connectivity and not in range of the watch, simple network requests frequently take > 30 seconds. very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I'm still experiencing the same issue in watchOS3. Slow network request. Especially when the watch app was freshly installed, the first network request is usually very slow. It can take up to 30s and timeout, but instantly in iOS.

But I find immediate improvement by using the iOS app to make the network request and send it to the watch app.

I use WCSession sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler in watchOS to notify the iOS app to make a specific network request. Then I send back the response from the network request via the replyHandler in session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler. There's only a short lag.

As a fallback, whenever sendMessage fails, I make the same request via the watch app, so it should still work if iPhone is not nearby.